# Debugger in compiled Electron App

Tags: debugging, exe, electron

I need the chrome debugger in a compiled Windows application(Electron App)

My main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron')
require('electron-debug')({showDevTools: true});
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 800})
   mainWindow.loadURL('https://camservices.prointernet.com/client.html');

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {

    mainWindow = null
  })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {

  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

But the Debugger don't show up on a compiled application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-debug), you can force it to appear in a production app by adding the `enabled` property.

```
require('electron-debug')({showDevTools: true, enabled: true});
```